# Is it true that ledger nano s can only store monero and one other coin?

Tags: hardware-wallet, ledger

I read somewhere that ledger nano s can only store monero and 1 other app due to space limitations on the device. Monero takes alot of space on the device and only one other app can be used. What other hardware wallets are in the works for monero integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Bitcoin, Ethereum, and Monero but now there's no more space. So, well, it's 3 at least.

Comment: Can be more than 3 if alts share a common code base.  For example, besides having Monero and Bitcoin loaded, Dash, LTC, and BCH could also be loaded and remain hot. This is because Dash, LTC, and BCH share BTC heritage - thus allowing code reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Ledger blue is claiming to [manage up to 11 assets simultaneously with the same hardware wallet](https://www.ledger.com/products/ledger-blue), and is as well [supported](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero)

Apart from ledger, two PR are in progress to support [trezor](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4241) and [others](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/4299), while [kastelo](https://github.com/monero-project/kastelo), the monero hardware wallet, is still being developed and should be released [later](http://kastelo.org).

Comment: Worth noting that Ledger Blue does not support BIP 39 seed word salting, i.e. passphrases.

Comment: I haven't been in such details. Just telling other hardware wallets are out there or coming soon.